# Package .bundle resources inside that they are not visible while distribution

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am trying to build a **Static Library** (`MyLibrary`) with bundle(`Resources`) which will hold resources like *images* and *CoreData* model file used within the static library.

I build and generated 2 files, under **Products** folder, `libMyLibrary.a` and `Resources.bundle` . I guess while distribution I need to send these 2 to the customer.

I noticed that *only* sending `libMyLibrary.a` won't work and I need to add a folder named `MyLibrary.swiftmodule` as well so that the app can identify the framework.

So To reduce all this (and the issue for making the Static library compatible with both Device and Simulator), I converted the **Static Library** to **Static Framework** using a *script* which finally generates **MyLibrary.framework**. I add this to the app that uses this library, add,

> Build Settings -> Search Path -> Compile Path = $(PROJECT_DIR)/MyLibrary.framework

and everything seems to be working.

My only problem is that the `Resources.bundle`, which I have provided to the customer which `MyLibrary` uses, **the client can see the contents inside that bundle**

[image]

Is there a way to somehow hide all these resources from the customer like for `MyLibrary.framework`, the customer cannot see the code.

Maybe some packing or something but in a way that the library can still access the `Resources.bundle`